# FindRoot question

Tags: equation-solving

I want FindRoot to do NOTHING if it doesn't find a solution within a domain. Consider the simple example:

```
FindRoot[x + 3 == 4, {x, 5, 5, 6}]
```

FindRoot returns the following:

FindRoot::reged: The point {5.} is at the edge of the search region {5.,6.} in coordinate 1 and the computed search direction points outside the region.

{x -> 5.}

How can i force FindRoot to do nothing if there is no solution within a domain?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

One possible way

```
 Quiet[Check[FindRoot[x + 3 == 4, {x, 5, 5, 6}], {}, FindRoot::reged]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
 Quiet[Check[FindRoot[x + 3 == 4, {x, 5, 5, 6}],, FindRoot::reged]]
```

Which return nothing.

```
 Quiet[Check[FindRoot[Sin[x] + Exp[x], {x, 0}], {}, FindRoot::reged]]
 (*{x -> -0.588533}*)
```

Comment: One might want to include `FindRoot::lstol`, `FindRoot::jsing`, maybe `FindRoot::cvmit` (others?). (+1)